# Bootstrap 3: Trouble with panels in responsive columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a page where my primary content is a series of Bootstrap panels. On `xs` screens, I want to have one panel in a row, so effectively one wide column. On `md` screens, I want to have two panels in each row, so effectively two columns. I am placing each panel in a column like so:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
   <div class="panel">
```

This works almost perfectly, but on medium screens, depending on the height of the panels, there is extraneous blank vertical space. see the image below for what I mean:

[image]

It is important that the ordering be the same on both the `xs` and `md` screen sizes. I.e, if on a xs screen the panels went:

```
A
--
B
--
C
```

Then on the medium screen size, it must go:

```
A  | B 
-------
C  |
```

jsBin is [here](http://jsbin.com/wanesatuci/edit?html,output) (or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2cdawkj/) if you prefer). Note that to reproduce, you'll need to widen output/preview pane so that it uses the medium screen size styling.

Comment: Don't forget, the CSS associated with `.row` requires its direct parent to be a `.container`!

Comment: I see a lot of a questions about this issue, but it's not something that `bootstrap` handles on it's own. Look into `masonry`: https://github.com/desandro/masonry

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks, I was able to use Masonry and get this fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Lewis' suggestion, I can accomplish this using [Masonry](https://github.com/desandro/masonry). It seems it is quite simple, and the following javascript snippet works so far:

```
$('.row').masonry(
    {itemSelector: '.col-md-6'}
);
```

This gets rid of the extraneous space and it works with the responsive design. My only issue so far is that collapsing/expanding the panels isn't quite right, but that wasn't part of the initial question here and I think I can fix it by just calling masonry again after the panel has been collapsed/expanded.